# Sigma 18-35mm F1.8 Canon

Tags: sigma, canon-70d

not sure if this is the right place to ask but I have been on the waiting list for the Sigma 18-35mm F1.8 DC HSM A Canon lens for a while. I'm getting pretty anxious, my wife is due in 2 weeks, so I'm trying to find a similar or better lens.

I have a 70d mount and an basically looking for the best, cheapest, all purpose lens.

Also would like to do video as well, so the sigma 18-35 seemed like a good choice since it had a quiet zoom and focus.

Comment: This *could* be the right place, but it's not a discussion forum — it's a Q&A site, so you'll get better results if you have a specific question. "What is the best, cheapest all-purpose lens?" is hard to answer, because if there were such a thing, there wouldn't be so many options on the market. Congratulations on your upcoming baby — my advice is to not lose any sleep over lens choice, because you'll need all the rest you can get. :) If you can't get the Sigma you're eying, grab any lens that matches the most important criteria that drew you to that one, and don't worry about "best".

Comment: I wouldnt call 18-35mm all purpose. tamron/sigma 17-50 F2.8 / canon F17-55 2.8 is though. they are also HSM/USM and have OS/IS.

Comment: I would get the Canon 17-55mm f/2.8. It is excellent, I've owned it and used it for the vast majority of my work on crop sensor Canon DSLRs. The sigma has a wider aperture sure, but the Canon is very handholdable throughout it's range especially with IS and f/2.8 is no joke.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'm going to start a new post and form it into a question.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you live? It should be available in most locations by know. Just do some research in other store nearby and make sure you can't get it from somewhere else.

If you can't get it in time I'm not sure what lens you're looking for as a replacement. The Sigma 18-35 mm f/1.8 is completely unique. There are simply no other lenses in this category. The combination of a zoom construction with a wide constant maximum aperture of 1.8 doesn't exist anywhere else. If the combination of a wide angle zoom with the wide aperture is what you're looking for you have to use multiple primes or sacrifice the aperture.

You say you're looking for the **best**, **cheapest** and an **all purpose lens**. Such a lens does not exist either. You can't get everything. The Sigma 18-35 mm f/1.8 sacrifices both cost and the all purpose aspect to achieve what it does.

I'm going to list different lenses that covers different combinations of your requirements as you cant get them all. But keep in mind that they are by no means a replacement for the Sigma 18-35 mm f/1.8 (if you want to have lenses with the same properties it's going to cost you a lot).

**Alternatives:**

- **Canon EF-S 18-135/3,5-5,6 IS** Quite cheap and an all purpose range, but lacks wide aperture properties. Also th image quality should be nowhere near that of the sigma.
- **Canon EF 24-105/4,0 L IS USM** A lot more expensive lens but compared to the former of superior quality. It still lacks a wide aperture though and also has distortion problems on its wide end.
- **Sigma 20/1,8 EX DG/Sigma 24/1,8 EX DG/Sigma 28/1,8 EX DG** If you're looking for the wide aperture in the range that the sigma zoom operates in there nothing else than primes to resort to and Sigma actually makes a couple of them in the middle of the zoom range that have the same aperture. There are also other brands that make similar lenses but to cover the range of the wide angle zoom you have to combine multiple primes and that will be costly.
- **EF-S 18-55 mm** If you just want a cheap lens or a lens until you get the sigma I would go for a second hand "kit lens" since they are very cheap (there are so many that got them with their cameras and have since bought other lenses). When you get the Sigma 18-35 mm f/1.8 you can sell this again for the same value.

Regarding video I guess the Sigma 18-35 mm f/1.8 is fine, but it lacks IS that can be handy. Unfortunately this is not common in that focal range.

Comment: Thanks Hugo. Im in Chicago, IL. I purchased the lens on Amazon. A buddy of mine purchased on B&H 2 months ago and he just have up on it because they never revived stock.

Comment: Thanks for the other suggestions. If you were going to take price out of the equation, what it's the best lens for both video and stills? My goal is to find one lens that I can just keep on the 70d. Right now I have the 18-55 that came with the lens and it works ok. The images aren't all that sharp though

Comment: @Tom Sorry mate but there truly are no one such lens. You've stated your needs to general. I think you should either use the kit lens until you get the Sigma or really think through your needs and then post a new question here asking for equipment recommendation being very specific of what you want. Good luck!